Analysis of randomized algorithm by number of "failing" inputs
I have a question more related to proof techniques.
Assume I have a problem P (of type yes/no) and I devise some randomized algorithm A. I then prove that in expectation (over the process of randomly flipping some coins, independent of input), the number of inputs for which my algorithm gives a wrong answer (false positive or negative) is o(1). Does this imply that my algorithm is correct with high probability (1 - o(1))?
Formally I would say yes, because by Markov's we can bound the probability that there exist some bad input by o(1). However, intuitively I'm not sure if it makes sense, since this kinda seems like having the input over some distribution (rather than having lets say an adversary which can try to always choose something bad). I have also never seen proofs following this technique, which I find weird. What do you think?

What is a correct randomized algorithm? How do you define correctness of a Monte-Carlo algorithm? In my opinion, there is no correctness, only bound probabilities of false positive/false negative.

When you say "probability" and "expectation", over what random process?  Taken over the choice of random coins?  OR are you also assuming the input is chosen randomly?

I mean correct with high probability (i.e. probability of false positive/negative is o(1)).
The random process is the choice of random coins. So the input is in some way "fixed" before I flip my coins.

If there are inputs for which your algorithm always gives wrong answer, then your algorithm is not correct unless you suppose randomness of input.
If for every input there is at least some non-zero probability of getting correct answer, and running algorithm multiple times you get potentially different answers, then there are some cases. I suppose that algorithm is polynomial to give references to corresponding complexity classes, but other statements are correct for exponential algorithms as well.
When correct answer is yes your algorithm gives yes with probability of at least $c = \mathrm{const} > 0$. When correct answer is no your algorithm always gives no. In this case you may repeat your algorithm while it gives the answer yes. After $k$ runs you conclude that there is at most $(1 - c)^k$ probability of giving false positive answer. And answer no is always correct. Such algorithm show that the problem belongs to the Randomized Polynomial-Time (RP) complexity class.
Everything is the same if algorithm gives yes if the answer is yes, and no with probability at least $c > 0$ if the answer is no. The only difference is the complexity class Complement of RP (coRP) of the underlying problem.
If your algorithm gives correct answer with some probability of at least $c = \mathrm{const} > \frac 12$ (but can give both false positive and false negative result), then running it bit enough number of times you have chance to distinguish yes and no answers with high probability. The error probability after $k$ runs is at most $\sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \binom{k}{i} c^i(1 - c)^{k - i}$. The underlying problem belongs to the Bounded-error probabilistic Polynomial-Time (BPP) complexity class.
If your algorithm gives correct answer with probability of at least $\frac 12$, then you need to run it potentially exponential or even super-exponential number of times to get some constant error-probability. The underlying problem belongs to the Probabilistic Polynomial-Time (PP) complexity class. Note that the difference with the previous case is that the probability may depend on input getting closer to $\frac 12$ for bigger inputs. This complexity class contains $\mathrm{NP}$.
To make a conclusion I would say that if you prove that your algorithm after certain number of runs (which may depend on input) gives wrong answer with probability of at most $\varepsilon$ for every input, you algorithm is considered as a correct probabilistic algorithm.
